# JTextField simply doesn't respond

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I have gone through the other question with same title but that isn't much helpful.
I am using GridBagLayout to build a form. But the JTextFields in my form simply doesn't respond. I click in it but it doesn't show the cursor. Thus i cant enter anything in it.
Code snippet is as follows:

```
  //textfields
    weighttf = new JTextField(20);

    go = new JButton("Get my Ideal Weight");
    go.setFont(centerpanelfont);

    centerpanel.setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();

    c.weightx=0.5;
    c.weighty=0.5;

    c.gridx=0;
    c.gridy=1;
    centerpanel.add(weighttf,c);
```

Comment: Try using weighttf.setEditable(true);

Comment: You're possibly blocking the Event Dispatching Thread somewhere. Can you produce a runnable example that replicates your problem?

Comment: Does the button work?

Comment: @Deepsthecoder Can you create a demo class related to your problem?

Comment: @MadProgrammer,  i evaluated the problem, i removed the windowlistener that i had added to the object of this centerpanel's container. And it worked. I dont know why it happened because of Windowlistener. Do you have any answer?

Answer (score 0):

try making textfield editable

```
weighttf.setEditable(true);
```

Comment: I checked the isEditable() value for the text field, its true. Well all other textfields show same malfunctioning. I usually use the layout  and design forms but this never happened before.

Comment: @Deepsthecoder try using different `Lauouts` for `centerpanel` (`FlowLayout()` or `GridLayout()`)

Comment: I have handled mouse events in the parent frame of this panel's container frame.Does that has this effect? Because this entire code works perfectly fine in a different project in Netbeans IDE.

Comment: If you are adding `MouseEvent` on `centerpanel` then its a very complex thing to identify any `component` inside that `centerpanel`. You need to handle mouseClick event but recognizing a particular component inside a panel using mouseClick event is a complex thing. So remove the mouseEvent from that panel

Comment: No i am not using the MousEvent on centerpanel. Well I tried different layouts and beleive me problem is still there. I am so frustrated now that i think there is an issue with memory location that these textfields have been allocated with. Its almost impossible i am aware. Where are the other geeks here. I am surprized greatly by this behaviour of textfields.

Comment: dear friend i evaluated the problem, i removed the windowlistener that i had added to the object of this centerpanel's container. And it worked. I dont know why it happened because of Windowlistener. Do you have any answer?